# Pandas groupby range, allow duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
char  |  num
-----------------
A     |  1
B     |  2
C     |  3
D     |  4
E     |  5
```

Is there a way to make a groupby object that will use a range of say 3 for 'num' to create groups like this:

Group 1:

```
char  |  num
-----------------
A     |  1
B     |  2
C     |  3
```

Group 2:

```
char  |  num
-----------------
B     |  2
C     |  3
D     |  4
```

Group 3:

```
char  |  num
-----------------
C     |  3
D     |  4
E     |  5
```

Rows would obviously be duplicated, but this is the result that I'm going for. I can think of some brute-force ways to achieve this, but I'm fishing for a elegant solution if it's out there.

Comment: Not sure, but for what you're describing looks like `pandas.DataFrame.rolling` would be good. Although I don't know what you're planning to do with the groups so hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.concat` trickery

```
n = len(df) - 2
g = pd.concat([df.iloc[i: i + 3] for i in range(n)]).groupby(np.arange(n).repeat(3))

g.get_group(0)

  char  num
0    A    1
1    B    2
2    C    3
```